# Google Maps API - Embedded YouTube in infoWindow fills screen

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, youtube

I'm using the Google Maps API v3, and have some embedded YouTube videos in infopanels. It displays and works correctly. Strange things happen when I close the panel.

- In IE8 the whole screen turns black, as the flash player goes full screen.  No video is seen, but if I click then the audio plays.
- In FF23 an error is shown in the console - TypeError: Value not an object. http://s.ytimg.com/yts/jsbin/www-embed-player-vflTdsFMk.js (line 220)

As a test I just took the code from Google's example (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/infowindow-simple), and changed the content to be a YouTube iframe embed code.  The same thing happens.

The test code is included below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Info windows</title>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
    <script>
        function initialize() {
          var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882,131.044922);
          var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 4,
            center: myLatlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
          }

          var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

          var contentString = "<iframe width='250' height='167' src='http://www.youtube.com/embed/eLRlHcCiNjg' frameborder='0' ></iframe>";

          var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
              content: contentString
          });

          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              position: myLatlng,
              map: map,
              title: 'Uluru (Ayers Rock)'
          });
          google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            infowindow.open(map,marker);
          });
        }

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div style="width: 800px; height: 800px;" id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The main issue is IE8.  I'd obviously prefer not to support it, but unfortunately I don't have that option.

Any help would be appreciated.

### Update

Changing the src of the iframe just before closing the panel seems to work.  Although the screen still flashes black for a second in IE.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow,'closeclick',function(){
  document.getElementById('theframe').src = "dummyfile.html";
});
```

Comment: I created a jsFiddle, but IE8 won't even load it.  You can see the error in FF though:  http://jsfiddle.net/ptH3G/1/

Answer (score 0):

try destroying the player-Object before closing the panel.
-> player.destroy()

Comment: You might be right, but I don't know how to get a reference to the player in the iframe.  I'd prefer not to have to use to YouTube API to embed the videos.